# How to blink the place holder on focusout in an input textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, user-interface

I want to blink the placeholder text on focus out .

This is my html code:

```
<input type="text" id="keyfob" class="customform col-sm-12 text-red" data-required='true' placeholder=" Please click here to Key Fob scanning work">
```

this is my jquery code:

```
$('#keyfob').on("focus blur", function(){
    $(this).attr("placeholder") == "" ? $(this).attr("placeholder", "Please click here for Key Fob scanning to work") : $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
});
```

[working js fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/kps06mjj/)

now i want to blink the placeholder text "Please click here to Key Fob scanning work".

So please can anyone help me ???

Answer (score 0):

here's jquery

```
function blink() {

if ($('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder')) {
 // get the placeholder text
 $('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder', '');
} 
else {
  $('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder', 'Placeholder Text...');
}
setTimeout(blink, 1000);
}
```

html

```
<body onload='blink()'>
<input type="text" on-click='blink()' id="keyfob" class="customform col-sm-12 text-red" data-required='true' placeholder=" Please click here to Key Fob scanning work">
```

Comment: Can u send me working of it in js fiddle,here it is not blinking for me

Comment: hey onfocus also its blinking bro ..i want to blink it only on focusout bro

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var clicked;
        $('#keyfob').focusout(function() {
            var s = $('#keyfob').attr("placeholder");
            clicked=true;
            blinking();    
        });
        $('#keyfob').click(function() {
            clicked=false;
            $('#keyfob').attr("placeholder", '');
        });
        function blinking() {
               if(clicked){
                     $('#keyfob').attr("placeholder", '');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#keyfob').attr("placeholder", 'Please click here to Key Fob scanning work');
                    setTimeout(blinking, 500);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
      });
   </script>

  </head>

    <body>
         <input type="text" id="keyfob" class="customform col-sm-12 text-red" data-required='true' placeholder="Please click here to Key Fob scanning work">
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: thanxs for responding. can u create a jsfiddle for above code,because it is not working for me

Comment: still the cursor and placeholder both are blinking @dileep i dont want blink both of them

Comment: Onfocus the placeholder text should be hide and onfocusout the placeholder text should be seen with the blinking effect.

Answer (score 0):

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476479/firefox-fails-to-animate-input-text-placeholder) that shows how it can be done with plain CSS only, without any JavaScript / jQuery.

Special credit for @Pinal who helped me to make it work on Firefox.