# Firefox fails to animate input text placeholder

Tags: html, firefox, input, css-animations

Answering some question I've tried to show how text input placeholder can be animated on blur using plain CSS without JavaScript / jQuery. I used the `:not(:focus)` pseudo class together with `input-placeholder` and put the blinking animation in it. On Chrome, IE and Opera it works perfectly, but on Firefox it fails.

If I try to set other property, for example `color:red` it works, so I'm sure that my code properly access the placeholder on blur. I also tried the same animation on a simple div with text and it works too. So, it seems that Firefox specifically fails to animate placeholder. Did I missed something or it's just a Firefox bug?

It's my code:

```css
#theInput:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-animation: simple-blink-text 1s step-start infinite;
}
#theInput:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
  animation: simple-blink-text 1s step-start infinite;
}
#theInput:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder {
  animation: simple-blink-text 1s step-start infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes simple-blink-text {
  0% { color: black }
  25% { color: transparent }
  100% { color: black }
}
@keyframes simple-blink-text {
  0% { color: black }
  25% { color: transparent }
  100% { color: black }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="theInput" placeholder="This field is required!">
```

and the same in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/rijii49/pen/OPzeKP?editors=110)

Comment: Try to use `-moz-animation` for Firefox

Comment: It was the first thing that I've tried and it doesn't help

Comment: Try the [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955163/imitating-a-blink-tag-with-css3-animations).

Comment: @RahulDesai This not an answers my question.

Comment: @AlexanderDayan I was just throwing in ideas that might help you.

Comment: @RahulDesai No problem, simply the answer that you've suggested not answered my question :) Please see solution by Pinal below, it's just great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `::-moz-placeholder` don't animate in Firefox. Try to use `@-moz-document url-prefix()` for FireFox:

```
#theInput:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-animation: simple-blink-text 1s step-start infinite;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  #theInput:not(:focus) {
    animation: simple-blink-text 1s step-start infinite;
  }
}
#theInput:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder {
  animation: simple-blink-text 1s step-start infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes simple-blink-text {
  0% { color: black }
  25% { color: transparent }
  100% { color: black }
}
@keyframes simple-blink-text {
  0% { color: black }
  25% { color: transparent }
  100% { color: black }
}
```

Comment: It works: http://codepen.io/rijii49/pen/YPYmxK !
Thank you for your amazing answer!

Comment: Further investigating this issue I found an additional problem. Because your solution animates the whole control and not a placeholder it blinks even if some text was inserted. However, I found the additional hack that solves it: if the control has 'required' attribute then ':invalid' pseudo class can be used to detect the empty value (see updated CodePen). Anyway, your answer was very good :)